# Css space issue with a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the following code at a some point of time i make the `rit.png` as `$("#img1").show();`

But there is a huge space between the image and the text.

How can the space be removed what is the issue here

```
  <div id="nav_bar" style="width:100%;height:25px;overflow:false;float:center;">
     <div id="resource" class="gorup" onclick="javascript:greoup();;" style="float:left;width:15%;border:1px solid #FFFFFF;"><img id="img1" src="/img/rit.png" style="float:left;border:none;" /><img id="img2" src="/img/w.gif" style="float:center;border:none;" />resource</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your CSS would be better off being in a separate file, not only is inline css hard to maintain but it's a pain to debug. Try setting the margin and the padding at 0 for those imates

Comment: The Firefox extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can help you debug such issues, and much, much more.

Comment: There is no false overflow.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp
There is no float center.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp
There is no Dana. There is only Zuul.

Comment: @lthibodeaux w3schools!! ahhh - http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Rajeev: There should be a delete link below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add display:block to style of your imgs.